# Randomly shuffle data and labels from different files in the same order

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle

l have two numpy arrays the first one contains data and the second one contains labels.
l want to shuffle the data with respect to their labels. In other way, how can l shuffle my labels and data in the same order.

```
import numpy as np
data=np.genfromtxt("dataset.csv", delimiter=',')
classes=np.genfromtxt("labels.csv",dtype=np.str , delimiter='\t')

x=np.random.shuffle(data)
y=x[classes]
```

do this preserves the order of shuffling  ?

Comment: You can combine data and class labels together, shuffle them [The order is preserved] and then separate them as input x and label y.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Generate a random order of elements with [`np.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) and simply index into the arrays `data` and `classes` with those -

```
idx = np.random.permutation(len(data))
x,y = data[idx], classes[idx]
```

Comment: data.shape is  (2240,3072) and classes.shape (2240,)

Answer (score 2):

the better and easy way is to use sklearn

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can concatenate the data and labels together, shuffle them and then separate them into **input x** and **label y** as shown below:

```
def read_data(filename, delimiter, datatype): # Read data from a file
    return = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter, dtype= datatype)

classes = read_data('labels.csv', dtype= np.str , delimiter='\t')
data = read_data('data.csv', delimiter=',')
dataset = np.r_['1', data, classes] # Concatenate along second axis

def dataset_shuffle(dataset): # Returns separated shuffled data and classes from dataset 
    np.random.shuffle(dataset)
    n, m = dataset.shape
    x = data[:, 0:m-1]
    y = data[:, m-1]
    return x, y # Return shuffled x and y with preserved order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip function

```
import numpy as np
data=np.genfromtxt("dataset.csv", delimiter=',')
classes=np.genfromtxt("labels.csv",dtype=np.str , delimiter='\t')

temp = list(zip(data, classes))
np.random.shuffle(temp)
data, classes = zip(*temp)
```