# TypeError: Trying to split data randomly in training and test set

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, typeerror

I want to take the first 70% of my shuffeled data as training data and the rest as test data, but I receive that strange error.

I have looked at other code examples with that error but don't get it, sorry.

```py
import numpy as np

segment_relative_path = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
idx = np.random.permutation(len(segment_relative_path))
train_data = segment_relative_path[idx[:int(0.7*len(idx))]]
```

This gives:

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

What do I have to change to avoid that error?

Comment: This will work - your code has a syntax error. 
    `train_data = segment_relative_path[:int(.7*len(idx))]`

Comment: Thanks for your anser, but what I basically want to do is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229034/randomly-shuffle-data-and-labels-from-different-files-in-the-same-order

Comment: The answer you mentioned is just randomizing the data [independent and dependent variables], not splitting it into train/test.

Comment: Yes I want to randomize the data and the use the first 70% of the randomized data for the training set.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an index array for a list. Lists accept only scalar integer indices.
However if you convert *segment_relative_path* into an array, it will work:

```
import numpy as np

segment_relative_path = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
idx = np.random.permutation(len(segment_relative_path))
train_data = np.array(segment_relative_path)[idx[:int(0.7*len(idx))]]
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!