# How to shuffle two numpy datasets using TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I wish to write a function in **TensorFlow 2.0** than shuffles data and their target labels before each training iteration.

Let's say I have two numpy datasets, X and y, representing data and labels for classification. How can I shuffle them *at the same time*?

Using `sklearn` it's pretty easy:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X, y = shuffle(X, y)
```

How can I do the same in **TensorFlow 2.0** ? The only tool I found in the documentation is [tf.random.shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/random/shuffle), but it takes only one object at a time, I need to feed two.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229034/.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of shuffling x and y , its much easier to shuffle their indices, so first generate a list of indices

`indices = tf.range(start=0, limit=tf.shape(x_data)[0], dtype=tf.int32)`

then shuffle these indices

`idx = tf.random.shuffle(indices)`

and use these indices to shuffle the data

```
x_data = tf.gather(x_data, idx)
y_data = tf.gather(y_data, idx)
```

and youll have shuffled data

Answer (score 3):

First convert them into `tf.data.Dataset` type.

```
x_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
y_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y)
```

Once done that, you can simply shuffle them:

```py
x_train, y_train = x_train.shuffle(buffer_size=2, seed=2), y_train.shuffle(buffer_size=2, seed=2)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
```

Use same `seed` in both of training variables so that you can shuffle your data without losing features-target relation.
You can even create a function to shuffle:

```py
BF = 2
SEED = 2
def shuffling(dataset, bf, seed_number):
   return dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=bf, seed=seed_number)

x_train, y_train = shuffling(x_train, BF, SEED), shuffling(y_train, BF, SEED)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to combine two datasets `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))`: `ValueError: Slicing dataset elements is not supported for rank 0`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to shuffle two arrays in the same way, you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Assuming X and y are initially NumPy arrays
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
# Make random permutation
perm = tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(tf.shape(X)[0]))
# Reorder according to permutation
X = tf.gather(X, perm, axis=0)
y = tf.gather(y, perm, axis=0)
```

However, you may consider using a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), which already provides a [`shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) method.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# You may use a placeholder if in graph mode
# (see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
# Shuffle with some buffer size (len(X) will use a buffer as big as X)
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(X))
```

Comment: how can we retrieve shuffled tensor X and Y with initial shape from the dataset object? thx in advance